# How to stop random redirects to HTTPS?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm facing a very annoying issue for a long time, perhaps someone could shed a light on this matter...

All my Wordpress websites at shared enrivonment at Hostinger all have the same bug: **Random redirects to HTTPS**

Sometimes it tries to load all resources through HTTPS - seems randomly.

Most of the time though, the redirect occurs on wp-admin, while saving posts, navigating, etc.

I already added this to .htaccess, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

These are default wordpress installations with no settings changed, it's really a bug, Hostinger already acknolwedged that. They said they would fix it, but it's been more than 6 months.

The certificate is issued to  ***.main-hosting.eu** and the error is **NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

How can I redirect ALL HTTPS requests to HTTP? How can I solve this bug?

-- Edit --

I confirmed it's a server-side bug, creating a simple debug.php with the following code: http://pastebin.com/n8PekA6d - the result is this: http://pastebin.com/t70nkTyj

Comment: You cannot redirect the HTTPS-requests to HTTP, because they never arrive at the server (the SSL error happens before any request gets made). I'm afraid you're looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: @DaanMeijer There's nothing I can do in a shared hosting environment? I'm at Hostinger's hands?

Comment: Well, I didn't say that. I feel it's very strange for a server configuration to randomly redirect you to SSL. My intuition is that the redirects come from within PHP, somewhere. However, if you are *sure* that it's not coming from PHP, and it depends on the hoster, there's very little you can do save for finding another hoster :(

Comment: It only happens with Wordpress websites. I have around 40 of them hosted there, and one or two custom MVC I made myself. Do you have any idea of how can I find where it might be redirecting to HTTPS in the giant mess of Wordpress code?

Comment: Usually, any redirects get done by `wp_redirect(...)`. It's defined in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`, around line 1143. Here you can experiment with `var_dump($location); debug_print_backtrace(); die();` to examine the call path that got you there :)

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I got this: http://pastebin.com/RC9iZtVG I'm investingating now auth_redirect() (plugabble.php line 1021).... http://pastebin.com/tzmZuimd

Comment: @DaanMeijer, I made a video for you, would you mind checking it out? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjD9vIE9p8Y

Comment: @DaanMeijer I confirmed it's a server-side bug, creating a simple debug.php with the following code: http://pastebin.com/n8PekA6d - the result is this: http://pastebin.com/t70nkTyj

Comment: I watched your video. I submitted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched your video. Although I would normally recommend enabling https, in this case you might be off better with:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] = 'http';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 80; //thanks to Lucas Bustamante
```

in your `wp-config.php`. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Defining `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] = 'http';` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '80';` on wp-config.php before the call to wp-settings.php fixed the issue. I confirmed it by echoing REQUEST_SCHEME before defining it, and even when it came from https, it loaded just fine. Thank you for your amazing debugging skills and will to help!

Comment: Always happy to help a fellow developer in need :)

Comment: Daan, can you please update your answer to include SERVER_PORT 80? It doesn't work without it